# Cube roots of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I need help with finding the cube roots of the complex number 27... I know that the obvious answer is three, but what is the less simple method to solving this?

Comment: Have you heard of [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Euler formula you have:
$$
1=\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)=e^{i2k\pi}
$$

Write: $27=27\times 1=27e^{i2k\pi}$ and find:

$$
\sqrt[3]{27e^{i2k\pi}}=3(e^{i2k\pi})^{\frac{1}{3}}=
3e^{\frac{i2k\pi}{3}}
$$
and for $k=1,2,3$ you find the three complex cubic roots of $27$.

Answer (score 3):

Tim's answer works, but another way to do it is using De Moivre's theorem. Using this theorem we find that the three complex roots of $27=27\left(\cos 0+i\sin 0\right)$ are given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
z_k&=\sqrt[3]{27}\left(\cos\frac{0+2\pi k}{3}+i\sin\frac{0+2\pi k}{3}\right)\\
&=3\left(\cos\frac{2\pi k}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $k=0,1,2$. This therefore gives us that the three cube roots of $27$ are:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
z_0=3\left(\cos\frac{2\pi\times 0}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi\times 0}{3}\right)&=3\\
z_1=3\left(\cos\frac{2\pi\times 1}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi\times 1}{3}\right)&=\frac{3\left(i\sqrt{3}-1\right)}{2}\\
z_2=3\left(\cos\frac{2\pi\times 2}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi\times 2}{3}\right)&=-\frac{3\left(i\sqrt{3}+1\right)}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Well you can solve the equation $x^3-27=0$

$$x^3-27=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9).$$

So, of course we get $3$ as a solution from the first factor.  To get the remaining solutions use the quadratic formula.